Position on literalist complaints
This question on basic reading material for a “complete newbie” has gone through a close-open cycle.
In its first incarnation I made an answer which started out as various philosophy-list type answers I had made at different times
Then it was closed.
In trying to salvage this question user JD tried to clean it up, a process that slightly invalidated existing answers. Curiously that point is explicitly discussed in this chat
Now user-Lowri is complaining regarding my answer:

This does not answer the question "Which books are typically recommended as being part of the philosophical canon by other philosophers?"

Note the first version didnt have »canon« and was more loosely worded.
There are three approaches here:

Revert the question to the matching form
Match (or else delete) the now-less-matching answer
Let it be

Personally I most like 3 because I am a strictly non-strict person!
As Lao Tzu had lyrically expressed ages ago

The more laws and restrictions there are, the poorer people become.
The more rules and regulations, the more thieves and robbers.
etc

However of late there is a definite tendency out here to get more legalistic.
It should be noted that there are two levels here:

the question of canon, an interesting point for the main site
the rules on which main runs — more suitable for here (meta)

Personally, I would wish that we focus more on the first,
but if the lay-of-the land has changed, it would be good to know (or have an edict!)

PS. (Under the assumption that user-Lowri flagged my answer as "Not an answer") I would like to express my gratitude that they have been cordial enough to express that in their comment

Well, my view is we should just let people discuss what they want to discuss. The question asker doesn't just want an answer to their question, they also want to talk to some people about it, with the feeling of human connection and attention. If they just wanted a list of philosophy books they could have just asked google for "philosophy reading list" and gotten something like https://www.phil.cam.ac.uk/system/files/suggested_preliminary_readings_updated_july_2023.pdf

@causative Ha Ha Very laissez faire! As you well know I like it like that. But thats not answering the specific question, viz. (a) A question after (community) edits has moved away from the existing answers (b) The question is now more conformant to SE rules; ie its 'better' in some sense (c) A complaint is raised that the old answer and the new question dont match.  The (meta) question then is “What will mods do in such circumstances?” Note: I dont expect as laissez faire as your comment seems to suggest. OTOH excessive legalism seems counterproductive

@causative Funnily enough the current complainant is not exactly consistent with their complaint.  See.

List/recommendation-based questions are generally considered off-topic, and the help center suggests the same: "If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format". Adding "recommended by philosophers" doesn't seem to fix it. (Sometimes such questions are allowed, but this is more done intentionally and by exception... and some sites might also not really bother to moderate such content, or accept it in some form.)

All true @NotThatGuy. But the question is somewhere else. At any time there is a status quo. So here there is a situation of a question with 4 answers, which has gone through a close-reopen cycle, that some people continue to want to expunge. The (meta) question is: What is the mod's stand?  What will the future stand be?  I believe you and I had a discussion on this a few days ago: What happens when the fit-to-be-closed rules are viewed differently by different people?

@NotThatGuy This (category of) question is a more special case. As my answer below indicates, many people come as noobs, asking unstructured confused noob questions.  It is a pattern. Does'nt having (a bunch) of standardized curated answers for such seem a desirable thing? In that situation the norm for closing would be This is a dup to  and not the absurd This is opinion based as was done to this question

It is a StackExchange-wide norm to not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.
If an answer no longer answers a question in edited form, it is

usually a sign of 1) an inappropriate edit to the question or 2) the question was really poor to begin with and should not have been answered in that form


I'll upvote because what you report is factually true, but what constitutes "invalidates existing answers" is a thinking game, and the best philosophy that gets done on the site.


If a question is closed, then to complain about edits is silly, because any edit that is proposed that gets the question re-opened is a good edit, even if it bends the rule. Because a closed question has little value.

A closed question has a lot of value, in my opinion.

Its answers are still relevant to the question that was asked and the person that asked them.
It is a signpost of what not to ask.
It ensures that other questions that have more value get the light of day.

A poorly-reopened question has negative value:

The answers are confusing to future readers, since they answer a question that is no longer being asked.
They don't ask the question that somebody originally came to the site to ask, so any new answers will be of limited use to them.

If a question would need to be fundamentally changed in a way that invalidates existing answers, I think it's preferable to ask a new question, especially if the OP of the question isn't involved in editing the question themselves.

+1 I don't disagree in the nature of your optimistic reach, however "fundamentally changed in a way that invalidates existing answers" is a bit vague.

As I performed the edit to advocate on behalf of the question, I think it's fair to say that there is a fine art to the process, and ultimately the site is, like all democratic entities, a compromise of differing approaches. Ultimately, the important question for me is, is the knowledge base fundamentally improved? Having the seed of a good question should be considered the starting point of a collaborative effort to ensure the spirit of the question is met with a good-faith effort to answer it.
If a question is closed, then to complain about edits is silly, because any edit that is proposed that gets the question re-opened is a good edit, even if it bends the rule. Because a closed question has little value. A certain ego-centrism seems to pervade many advocates thinking such as, the community should have no say, or it's my way or the highway. But inevitably, there is a mechanism in place to foster democratic representation. Thus, as it has been previously observed, compromise results in no party getting everything they want.
Thus, those who operate on narrow, legalistic interpretations of the rules have to accept that others have a broader interpretation of the imperatives. Of course, it goes the other way. Sometimes otherwise defensible and improvable questions get closed. This creates a certain arbitrary quality to Q&A depending on which parties are voting at which time. To me, the real philosophy conducted by the site is when parties realize their ambitions may be thwarted by others. Over the last 5+ years, I have seen users role in with an attempt to "improve" the site only to watch their ambitions swallowed up by the indifference of many, and the intents of a few. But this is a natural state of democracy.

This site is definitely a democracy: it is the worst site except for all the others. That's why I'm here :-)

Given how frequent such questions are I would like to express the wish that curating these is a more purposive activity.
Here's a quick sampler:
What are some good introductions to philosophy?
Roadmap for self study in philosophy
Best way to start philosophy?
tips for future philosophy student

My Tip: don't waste too much time here! But I don't always take my own advice.

@ScottRowe Good time (and age ) to hear God speaking
